# AWS API gateway domain mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have domain with aws example.com, currently I have record set so that when user goes to example.com, it serves static website from S3 (done with angular). Now, I have backend api (Lambda and API gate way), which is has url something like,

```
https://randomid.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/Prod/api/getSomething?id=1
```

so, what I am trying to do is if front end makes a http call to `example.com /api/getSomething?id=1`, it should return me data (since I am using relative urls).

I was reading aws documentation, it seems i cannot use root domain, I have to use subdomain (api.example.com), I am ok with it. But, I am not sure how can i do that, any help would be appreciated.

Also, I may move my front end to subdomain (web.example.com), if I do that, with my backend at (api.example.com, hope fully I will figure this part), will I run into CORS issue?

Answer (score 1):

Go through [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) AWS developer guide to change the domain name.

Apart from DNS configurations, it also requires to have a SSL certificate for the custom domain (Which could be taken from [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) for free).

Also note that an API's custom domain name can be the name of a subdomain or the root domain (aka, zone apex) of a registered Internet domain.

If your Web and API have different subdomains, it will run into CORS. However you can setup a CloudFront distribution infront of both Web and API to avoid CORS.

Comment: Another option for the CORS issue, is to enable CORS on the api, instead of setting up a cloudfront distribution.